# Getting unexpected token when doing onclick

Tags: javascript, php

I'm using an `onclick` event to call a JS function from PHP. Here is my code:

I'm inside a function so I need to do it via PHP, because then I do a return:

```
$html = '<input type="checkbox" checked value="1" id="setGetSku" name="setGetSku" onclick="setGetSku('.$row['sku'].')">';

return $html;
```

My JS:

```
function setGetSku(sku) {   //Gettng error here
    var conf = confirm("Are you sure?");
    if (conf == true) {

          .... my code...
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you see if you do inspect element?, what is the complete error when you click?

Comment: This one: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } (function(event){setGetSku( })

Comment: What is the value of `$row['sku']` in this example

Comment: please try this: `$html = "<input type='checkbox' checked value='1' id='setGetSku' name='setGetSku' onclick='setGetSku(".$row['sku'].")'>";` it is not tested but should work

Answer (score 1):

Just add quote ....onclick="setGetSku("'.$row['sku'].'")"...

Comment: Good catch. I somehow missed that part. shhhhhhhhh. Actually it should be `onclick="setGetSku(".$row['sku'].")"` instead.

Comment: Im still getting: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }
(function(event){setGetSku(
})
not sure whats wrong....

Comment: please care about quotes

Comment: null yes, danke

Comment: Is this correct answer please mark as correct answer

Answer (score 0):

Ok i have fixed, in case someone is looking for the same this is the answer, you need to pass an string using quote in my case:

```
$html = '<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="setGetSku" onclick=setGetSku("'.$row['sku'].'")';
```